# transfer code from windows to linux

Tags: c++

while transfer code from visual studio 2010 to linux we encounter the next message (compiler):

> "Tank.h:24: fatal error: can`t write PCH file: Disk quota exceeded"

```
class Tank: public Vehicle
{
public:
    Tank(char* veID, char* model, int numOfBooms, char* baseName);
    ~Tank();
     virtual ostream& Print (ostream& res) const;
     virtual void SetDistanceToTreat(double dis);
     virtual double GetDistanceToTreat() const {return m_distanceToTreat;}
     virtual void IntializeDistanceToTreat(); 

private:
    double m_distanceToTreat;
    int m_numOfBooms;

};

inline ostream& operator<<(ostream &res, const Tank& t) //line 24
{ return t.Print(res); }
```

it works perfectly in windows

Answer (score 1):

`Disk quota exceeded` - seems like you have problems writing a file to the disk. Check the permissions and free disk space. Maybe the root gave your user just a limited disk space, which you have already used?

Comment: The problem was that the inline function should be in the header of the father class "Vehicle" and not in the derive classes .